# CSS Bottom Border Not Appearing in Left and Right Columns

Tags: html, css, border, blogger

Help! I've read every question here and every tutorial online… but I can't seem to make the left and right column bottom border appear on my layout that I'm trying to put together.

[Here is a link](http://fashionfrugalitytests.blogspot.com) where I am currently working on it.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My current css is:

```
.main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer .fauxcolumn-inner {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: white url(http://i1109.photobucket.com/albums/h423/thesinglemomoirs/templates/pinkcupcake/38d73024.png) repeat scroll top left;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.fauxcolumn-outer .fauxborder-left, .fauxcolumn-outer .fauxborder-right, .fauxcolumn-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to set the box-sizing like so:

```
.fauxcolumn-inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Your problem is that without box-sizing to border-box when you set your height to 100%:

```
.fauxcolumn-outer .fauxborder-left,
.fauxcolumn-outer .fauxborder-right,
.fauxcolumn-inner {
    height: 100%
}
```

and THEN add margins, padding or borders, your true height ends up being greater than 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourclass {
    border-bottom:thick solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace border with an inner box shadow with no blur:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000000;
```